# How to insert image in jQuery Cropit without input file

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

If you look the default setting in jQuery Cropit the code like this

```
   <div class="image-editor">
      <div class="cropit-image-preview"></div>
      <div class="image-size-label"> Resize image </div>
      <input type="range" class="cropit-image-zoom-input">
      <input type="hidden" name="image-data" class="hidden-image-data" />
      <input type="file" class="cropit-image-input">
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
```

Yes, it's using an input file to upload a new image.
But, I want to insert my image without input file, I need to insert with input text and parsing some URL. How can I do that?

Comment: you can hide the input type file then do the click event on click of text

Comment: and how I can insert the URL for a new image? jQuery Cropit just work if you select an image in input file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// Sets image source.
$imageCropper.cropit('imageSrc', 'http://placekitten.com/g/1280/800');
```

Source: [Cropit Documentation](http://scottcheng.github.io/cropit/)

So all you have to do is add a text input, then user that value (where the value is a url to an image file):

```
$imageCropper.cropit('imageSrc', $('#myinput').val());
```

Comment: Can you give me a link to your jsfiddle? Because it's work for the first time. If I run more than two times, it gives you same Image when you set the first time